# show that a set is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Let $S_1, S_2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with $S_1$ convex. Show that the following set is convex. $$\{\, x \mid x + S_2 \subseteq S_1\,\}$$

---

I understand that I need to express this set as an intersection of convex sets. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set equals $$\bigcap_{s\in S_2}(S_1-s) $$
ans is convex as translates and intersections of convex sets are convex.

Answer (score 1):

let $s_2\in S_2$, we have to show if $x+s_2=s_1\in S_1, y+s_2=s'_1\in S_1$, then $tx+(1-t)y+s_2\in S_1$. We have: $tx+ts_2+(1-t)y+(1-t)s_2=tx+(1-t)y+s_2=ts_1+(1-t)s_1'$.$ts_1+(1-t)s_1'\in S_1$ since $S_1$ is convex